# react-redux Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In this Code, I use react-redux and react-router. the react-redux version is old but I want to know where I went wrong in this piece of code (in this version of react-redux and react-router I meant).
I try to get **ingredients** in **main.jsx** and use it in **OrderSummary** Component but I got errors like:

- Cannot read properties of undefined,
- state not found.

[github repository](https://github.com/alimirzaeimajd/Umami-Burger)

## main.jsx:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./store/reducer";

export default function Main(props) {
  const store = createStore(
    reducer /* preloadedState, */,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  );

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<App />} />
            <Route
              path="/burger-builder/order-page"
              exact
              element={
                <OrderSummary
                  ingredients={props.ingredients}
                  totalPrice={props.totalPrice}
                />
              }
            />
            <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Main />);
```

## BurgerBuilder.jsx:

```
import * as actionTypes from "../../store/action";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function BurgerBuilder(props) {
return (
    <>
      <Burger ingredients={props.ings} />
      <BurgerControls
        addIngredients={props.onIngredientAdded}
        removeIngredients={props.onIngredientRemoved}
        totalprice={props.totalPrice}
        disabled={disableButton}
      />
    </>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    ings: state.ingredients,
    price: state.totalPrice,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onIngredientAdded: (ingName) =>
      dispatch({ type: actionTypes.ADD_INGREDIENT, ingredientName: ingName }),
    onIngredientRemoved: (ingName) =>
      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.REMOVE_INGREDIENT,
        ingredientName: ingName,
      }),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BurgerBuilder);
```

*part of*

## reducer.js:

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ADD_INGREDIENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                ingredients: {
                    ...state.ingredients,
                    [action.ingredienName]: state.ingredients[action.ingredientName] + 1
                },
                totalPrice: state.totalPrice + INGREDIENT_PRICES[action.ingredientName]
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Main` component, you're passing `props.ingredients` and `props.totalPrice` to `OrderSummary`, but `props` is not defined in `Main` -- you don't pass any when you render `Main` with `root.render(<Main />);`.

To get around this, you can connect `OrderStatus` to the Redux store like you do with `BurgerBuilder`:

```
function OrderSummary(props) {
    // access mapped props
    const { ingredients, totalPrice } = props;

    // ...
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        ingredients: state.ingredients,
        totalPrice: state.totalPrice,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OrderSummary);
```

Then, in `Main`, render `OrderSummary` without `props`:

```
<Route path="/burger-builder/order-page" exact element={<OrderSummary />} />
```

---

Also, there's a typo in your reducer. You wrote  `action.ingredienName` instead of `action.ingredientName` in the `ADD_INGREDIENT` case. Here's the fixed reducer.js:

```js
case actionTypes.ADD_INGREDIENT:
    return {
        ...state,
        ingredients: {
            ...state.ingredients,
            [action.ingredientName]: state.ingredients[action.ingredientName] + 1
        },
        totalPrice: state.totalPrice + INGREDIENT_PRICES[action.ingredientName]
    };
```